# PHP - Append to object?

Tags: php, append

I am having issue how to append to a object.

I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Anteris\Autotask\API\Contacts\ContactEntity as array in...
```

If it remove the part with the `MobilPhone` and `Email` if statements it works fine.

The code:

```
Create new contact
$contact = new Anteris\Autotask\API\Contacts\ContactEntity([
'id' => 0, // Autotask requires that new entities have an ID of 0
'companyID' => intval($Companyid),
'firstName' => $Fornavn,
'lastName' => $Efternavn,
'isActive' => 1,
'phone' => $Telefon,
]);

Check if MobilPhone filled out
if (empty($MobilTelefon)) {
} else {
$contact['mobilePhone'] = $MobilTelefon;
}

Check if Email filled out
if (empty($Email)) {
} else {
$contact['emailAddress'] = $Email;
}

Create in Autotask
$client->contacts()->create( $contact );
```

Comment: Well, the message is quite clear, you are trying to use an object as an array which are two different things. You don't show the content of the Contact entity so it's hard to help, but if you do have mobilePhone and emailAddress properties in this entity. Then you would have to set the property. Let's assume and the properties exist and are public you would have to do something like `$contact->emailAddress = $email` instead of trying to use it as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first line you're creating an instance of the `ContactEntity` class. `$contact` is the variable that holds an *instance* of the class. `$contact` is now an object.

Yet in the lines that generate the error, you're *using the object as an array*, which is not possible. Object properties are accessed using the `->` operator. Array elements are accessed using `[]` notation.

In the [Anteris source](https://github.com/Anteris-Dev/autotask-client/blob/master/src/API/Contacts/ContactEntity.php), you can see that
on line 42 `mobilePhone` is defined as `public ?string $mobilePhone;`. An object property.

So in your code, instead of writing this:

`$contact['mobilePhone'] = $MobilTelefon;`

You have to write this:

`$contact->mobilePhone = $MobilTelefon;`

Same goes for the other variables.

Comment: Also, you can rewrite your `if (empty())` statements to check if they're not empty (`if (!empty($MobilTelefon)) { ... }`, so you don't have to write an empty block that does nothing!

Comment: Thanks, everything works perfect now, and did rewrite the if statements :)